# Django: Field missing when queried

Tags: django, django-models

I'm having some trouble querying for my CalculatedAmt field in my database. In fact, according to the error code, the field does not even exist. However, I have included it in my Models.py and it can even be seen in my admin interface on Django.

Here are my codes:

*Model.py - I didn't join the tables because I didn't need the join for my queries*

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    Customer_Name_P = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="missing")
    Customer_TelNo = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="missing")
    Postal_Code = models.CharField(max_length=6, default="missing")

def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.Customer_Name_P

class Transaction(models.Model):
    DocRef = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
    DocDate = models.DateField()
    AcCrIsMinus1 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
    AcCurWTaxAmt = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
    HomeWTaxAmt = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
    CalculatedAmt = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="missing")
    ProjectCode = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
    Sales_Person = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
    AcCode = models.CharField(max_length=8,default="missing")
    Customer_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="missing")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.id


class Salesperson(models.Model):
    Sales_Person_P = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing",primary_key=True)
    Sales_Person_Name = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
    Sales_Person_Contact = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.Sales_Person_P


class Account(models.Model):
    AcCode_P = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="missing",primary_key=True)
    Customer_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="missing")
    AcCur = models.CharField(max_length=3, default="missing")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.AcCode_P
```

*Query in shell (for a table):*

```
Transaction.objects.all().filter(Sales_Person=Sales_Person).values('DocRef','DocDate','AcCrIsMinus1','HomeWTaxAmt','ProjectCode','Customer_Name','Location')
```

*Error Message:*

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'CalculatedAmt' into field. Choices are: AcCode, AcCrIsMinus1, AcCurWTaxAmt, Customer_Name, DocDate, DocRef, HomeWTaxAmt, Location, ProjectCode, Sales_Person, id
```

*Here's a screenshot of a Transaction instance from the admin interface:*
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2X9X.png)

*Screenshot of the output for python manage.py showmigrations:*
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72P8D.png)

*Screenshot of migrations 0001_initial file*
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSEE5.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`? Have you checked your database?

Comment: Yes i have, in fact I only have 1 migration file, which already contains the field. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I imported the Transaction instances through reading a csv file, and the CalculatedAmt was a calculated field using the formula "row['HomeWTaxAmt']*row['AcCrIsMinus1']". However, the admin interface does reflect the correct amount as the value of the field.

Comment: Can you update your question with the `./manage.py showmigrations` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error does not say that the field is **missing**. The **FieldError exception** is raised when there is a problem with a model field. This can happen for several reasons:

- A field in a model clashes with a field of the same name from an
  abstract base class
- An infinite loop is caused by ordering
- A keyword cannot be parsed from the filter parameters
- A field cannot be determined from a keyword in the query parameters
- A join is not permitted on the specified field
- A field name is invalid A query contains invalid order_by arguments

Just for your information, for a field which does not exist there is a **FieldDoesNotExist** exception. It is raised by a model’s `_meta.get_field()` method when the requested field does not exist on the model or on the model’s parents.

The error is because you are fetching `all()` first then try to filter. When you fetch all you get all fields and then not include `CalculatedAmt` in your values.

```
t = Transaction.objects.filter(Sales_Person__iexact=Sales_Person)
```

`t` object will be containing all the field of Transaction so no need for `.values`, you can retrieve them by `t.CalculatedAmt` for example. P.s. `ixact` means exact matching without caring for case-sensitiveness.

Moreover, I assume you have tried to connect 2 models together with `Sales_Person field`. But you are doing it in the wrong way.

You should use one of the `OnetoOne`, `ForeignKey` or `ManytoMany` relationships. I will use `ForeignKey` assuming that ***a salesperson can have many transactions but each transaction can only belong to one person***.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
DocRef = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
DocDate = models.DateField()
AcCrIsMinus1 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
AcCurWTaxAmt = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
HomeWTaxAmt = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
CalculatedAmt = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="missing")
ProjectCode = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
Location = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
Sales_Person = models.ForeignKey('Salesperson', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
AcCode = models.CharField(max_length=8,default="missing")
Customer_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="missing")

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.id


class Salesperson(models.Model):
    Sales_Person_P = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing",primary_key=True)
    Sales_Person_Name = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")
    Sales_Person_Contact = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="missing")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.Sales_Person_P
```

Comment: Oh! but when they gave the list of fields, the field CalculatedAmt did not appear, so I though the field was missing. Is there something wrong with my model or query that led to this error?

Comment: If you have used the same names in other models you should use related_name in those fields so, when you query or filter you can use those names

Comment: okay sure! but I don't have any fields with the same name in other models. I have updated my question with my full models.py

Comment: Changed my filtering code and managed to get it! Thank you!! Thanks for your advice on joining the tables too! I will give it a try :)

Comment: You are more than welcome, glad to be able to help!!